# If $z,w\in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, then $|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ iff $w=tz$ for some $t\gt 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

This is Exercise EP $8$ from Fernandez and Bernardes's book *Introdução às Funções de uma Variável Complexa* (in Portuguese).

> If $z,w\in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, then $|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ iff $w=tz$ for
>   some $t\gt 0.$

I supposed that $|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ and by squaring it I got  $\operatorname{Re}(z\bar{w})=|z||w|$ and I am stuck.  I would appreciate a hint in this question.

Comment: $z=1$, $w=0$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $w=tz$ can be restated as a claim about the arguments of $z$ and $w$.

Take $\mathrm{Re}(z\bar{w})=|z| |w|$ and divide by the RHS, then write $z/|z|=e^{i\theta}$ and $w/|w|=e^{i\phi}$.