# On showing that $|z + w| = |z| + |w|$ if and only if $z = tw, t > 0, z, w \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Even after re-reading posts [If $z,w\in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, then $|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ iff $w=tz$ for some $t\gt 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116319/if-z-w-in-mathbbc-times-then-zw-zw-iff-w-tz-for-some-t-gt) and [$|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ iff $z=cw$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512101/zw-zw-iff-z-cw?noredirect=1&lq=1) a dozen times, I still don't understand how the proof for the implication $|z + w| = |z| + |w| \implies w = tz, t >  0$ works. Specifically, in [$|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ iff $z=cw$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512101/zw-zw-iff-z-cw?noredirect=1&lq=1) it is shown that $|z + w| = |z| + |w| \Longleftrightarrow \mathrm{Re}(z\cdot \bar{w}) = |z|\cdot |w|$, and in [If $z,w\in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, then $|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ iff $w=tz$ for some $t\gt 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116319/if-z-w-in-mathbbc-times-then-zw-zw-iff-w-tz-for-some-t-gt) the argument rests on using the exact same equality and mentioned above, but i.) dividing by the RHS ii.) writing $z/|z| = e^{i\theta}, w/|w| = e^{i\theta}$.

In both of these approaches it is unclear to me how we can state anything about the relationship of $w$ to $z$ by inspecting the real part of the product $z\cdot \bar{w}$, i.e. how can the $\mathrm{Re}(z\cdot \bar{w})$ be manipulated any further?

Edit: My bad, an additional condition is that $z \neq 0, w \neq 0$.

Comment: Something seems wrong.  Went to prove this another way and hit the stumbling block on one of the numbers real, the other imaginary.  $z=1$,  $w=i$ are orthogonal,  the equality holds,  but you don't have a real $t>0$ relating them....

Comment: Go for the Argand diagram and plot the points z and w.

Comment: Write out the defn. and then you can apply Minkowskis inequality.

Comment: @Alan: Equality does not hold in $|1+i| = \sqrt 2 < 2 = |1| + |i|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry for the inconvenience, I forgot to mention that $z \neq 0, w \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\operatorname{Re}(z\cdot \bar{w}) = |z|\cdot |w| = |z\cdot \bar{w}|
$$
implies that
$$
 t = z\cdot \bar{w}
$$
is a real and non-negative number, and so is (assuming $w \ne 0$)
$$
 \frac{z}{w} = \frac{z\cdot \bar{w}}{w\cdot \bar{w}} = \frac{t}{|w|^2}
$$

Comment: I don't want to remove the acceptance, but I have to ask for further clarification on why $t = z \cdot \bar{w}$ is real based on $\mathrm{Re}(z \cdot \bar{w}) = |z|\cdot |w| = |z \cdot \bar{w}|$? I understand the the first equality in your response implies that the real part of $|z \cdot \bar{w}|$ is non-negative, but why would this show that the imaginary part is zero?

Comment: @EpsilonAway: If a complex number $\zeta = a+ib$ satisfies $\operatorname{Re}(\zeta) = \zeta$ then $a = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and that is only possible if $b=0$ and $a \ge 0$.

Comment: Argh, of course! From $\mathrm{Re}(z\cdot \bar{w}) = |z \cdot \bar{w}| = \sqrt{\mathrm{Re}(z \cdot \bar{w})^2 + \mathrm{Im}(z \cdot \bar{w})^2}$ we get necessarily that $Im(z \cdot \bar{w}) = 0$

Comment: Exactly. (And I meant $\operatorname{Re}(\zeta) = |\zeta|$.)